# ASP.NET Core 2.2 error when setting up DBContext (works in Kestrel, not in IIS Express)

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, kestrel

I have a  .Net Core 2.2 web project where I set up the dbcontext connections in the **Startup.cs** file:

```
services.AddDbContext<FirmDirectoryContext>(options =>  
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultDatabase")));
```

When I run this is Kestrel it works, but if I try to run it using IIS Express I get the following:

> *{System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString*

The connection string is obviously set in the **appsettings.json** file, or Kestrel would fail as well?

Comment: What is the actual line where you got this exception?

Comment: The "services.AddDbContext" line

Comment: Can you please share how your appsettings.json file looks like with some mock values?

Comment: could you please share the startup.cs and the program.cs code to trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in my **Program.cs** file.  I had copied some code I used from a .NET Core 2.1 project

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .UseWebRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot") // THIS LINE FIXES STATIC FILES ON PROD
     .UseIISIntegration()
     .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Once I edited it to remove the **Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()** code it works.

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseIISIntegration()
     .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Now I'll have to test on the server to see if it still works.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your appsettings.json looks like, but you should have a section in your json file like this :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultDatabase": "<Your connection string>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is set as development, dotnet gets connection string from appsettings.development.json.

Make sure you have set connection string there as well.